# Bind ItemsPanelTemplate of ListBox

Tags: silverlight

Silverlight (even 4, sigh) seems unable to have a ListBox change ItemsPanel at runtime.  I'm already successfully binding my ItemTemplate, which works fine, but ItemsPanel, once set, doesn't seem to be able to be changed at runtime.  Are there any workarounds for this?

Most (all) of what I've found online works for WPF, but not Silverlight.

EDIT:

Here's the XAML of my ListBox

```
<ListBox Visibility="{Binding ListBoxVisible}" ItemsPanel="{Binding lbItemsPanelTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BookSource}" ItemTemplate="{Binding ListBoxItemTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

The ItemTempate binding works perfectly, but the ItemsPanel binding will not work.  there have been other postings on this, but no real solutions, at none that work with *Silverlight* (just WPF)

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying you can't do `<ListBox><ItemsPanelTemplate><DESIREDPANELTYPE></ItemsPanelTemplate>...rest of xaml</ListBox>`?

Comment: See edit - I'm trying to bind the ItemsPanel, and have it change at runtime.